# Проверить существование переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

подскажите пожалуйста почему следующий код не может проверить существование переменной в глобальной области видимости?

```
а = 'dg'

print(globals())

if a in globals():
    print('y')
else:
    print('n')
```

сообщение об ошибке такое:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Python33\projects\textPad\q.py",
> line 5, in <module>
>     if a in globals(): NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что a должно быть строкой

```
if 'a' in globals():
    print('y')
else:
    print('n')
```

Comment: я пробовал и строкой. но не определяет.
такой код выводит 'n'.......
а = 'dg'

if 'a' in globals():
    print('y')
else:
    print('n')

Comment: не знаю тогда в чем у вас проблема.
у меня данный код

    a = 'dg'
    
    if 'a' in globals():
        print('y')
    else:
        print('n')

выводит 'y'

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, проверяйте раскладку клавиатуры, когда вводите схожие символы.

Comment: Да, кстати, первая a - русская)

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin проверьте, не русская ли `'a'`, не внутри ли функции у Вас этот код...

Comment: извиняюсь. действительно проблема была в раскладке