# Как мне сделать чтобы если пользователь вёл название 1 переменной во 2, то 2 принимала значение 1

Tags: python, list, переменные

Вот возникла незадача мне надо сделать так чтобы если пользователь вёл название одной переменной в другую, то другая принимала значение первой.
То как я это вижу вы можете видеть внизу в коде.
Сложность возникает в том что мне нужно поставить условие к каждой переменной, но в моем коде их около 50 побочных(имеющие значение) и такое нужно провернуть ещё с 3 основных(в которые нужно засунуть данные), что в итоге мне даст 300 строчек кода.
Так что если можете как-то уменьшить содержание, то пожалуйста помогите

Пример: **x = 5 , y = 7**

Пользователь вводит в переменную t значение x

```
t = input("x или y")
```

Если переменная равна имени хоть одной переменной, то она принимает её значение.

```
If t =="x":
    t = x

Elif t == "y":
    t = y

x,y,z = 5,8,2
t = input()
If t == "одна из переменной":
    t = этой переменной
```

Comment: Можете перефразировать ваш вопрос и добавить больше детале и примеров? Вообще не понятно, что у вас есть сейчас, с чем возникли сложности и какого поведения вы ожидаете

Comment: В вашем вопросе уже есть весь нужный код.

Comment: Код то есть, только как я написал этот код будет занимать 300 строк, поэтому я решил спросить можно ли сократить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в python3 обратиться к переменной по имени, используя значение из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591460/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-python3-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: ну или другие дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/881470/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/294170/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1357065/178576), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230591/178576), [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197589/178576), и т.д. и т.п.